# Bower dependencies for Angular in Eclipse

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, dependencies, bower

I have a web app I am launching from Eclipse using Spring Boot. I am trying to use Angular modals to have a nice looking confirm delete modal and I was following [this tutorial](http://www.dwmkerr.com/the-only-angularjs-modal-service-youll-ever-need/) to get the right dependencies. The Bower install seemed to go well:

```
bower install angular-modal-service --save
```

And I copy this into my html:

```
<script src="bower_components\angular-modal-service\dst\angular-modal-service.min.js"></script>
```

And I add the dependency in my Angular file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angularModalService']);
```

But that is the point at which it fails. If I launch my app I just get a blank page, nothing at all loads. My console output from Chrome's developer tools gives me:

```
Uncaught Error: No module: angularModalService
```

This is a general problem I have had, anytime I try to add a dependency with something like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['DEPENDENCY']);
```

it doesn't work. Is there something more I need to do in Eclipse in order for it to get it to pick up on my Bower dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

When you have such problem, we can't resolve it for you.
But we can give you some advices to resolve this kind of problem :

- **Identify the problem**. Open the developper tools of your navigator (**F12**), then the **console**. If you have nothing here, try to refresh. Angular will let you know if there is a dependency injection problem.
- **Check if you didn't forgot something**. You have to import in your page angular, THEN angular-modal-service, THEN your application. The order is important.
- **Check if the module you want to use doesn't depend to something else**. In your case, do this module needs bootstrap JS files ? Again, take a look at the console. It's here to help you.

Comment: That's just not true. Someone else might have had my exact problem before and thought of a way to resolve it. I am doing what you said though and will update my post with the info, it confirmed it is not finding the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not specifying `type="text/javascript` in the script declaration causes your browser not to parse and execute the script? It is required in HTML < 5. Try adding that. Maybe that will help. Post your HTML file, if it still does not work.